# impossible to use pip

Tags: python, pip

I start on Python, I try to use *mathplotlib* on my code but I have an error `"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'"` on my *cmd*. So I have tried to use *pip* on the *cmd*: `pip install mathplotlib`.

But I have an other error `"No python at 'C:\...\Microsoft Visual Studio\..."`.

Actually I don't use Microsoft Studio anymore so I uninstall it but I think I have to change the path for the *pip* module but I don't know how... I add the link of the script  of the Python folder on the variables environment but it doesn't change anything. How can I use *pip* ?

Comment: What exactly did you add to the environment variables?

Comment: Maybe try `pip3 install` since you tagged python3, not python2.

Comment: What happens if you type `python` in the command prompt (cmd)?

Comment: @mkrieger1 : I have created a classic folder with the folders "include", "lib", "scripts"... For this I created an environnement with windows visual studio...
So I tried to add the adress of the environnment folder, the lib folder and the scripts folder to the environment variables.
If I type 'python' , the cmd answer me: " No python at 'C:\Program Files (*86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe'"
 This path don't exist anymore because I uninstall Microsoft Visual Studio. Python is opened normally when I type 'py'. (Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: @tommysCesaille it's the same issue when I wrote 'pip3 install'

Comment: Did you install Python at all?

Comment: I think yes, I did the classic installation and I add python to the environmnent variables automatically...

Comment: delete that path from windows

Answer (score 1):

Your setup seems messed up. A couple of ideas:

- *long term solution*: Uninstall everything related to Python, make sure your `PATH` environment variables are clean, and reinstall Python from scratch.
- *short term solution*: Since `py` seems to work, you could go along with it: `py`, `py -3 -m pip install <something>`, and so on.
- If you feel comfortable enough you could try to salvage what works by looking at the output of `py -0p`, this should tell you where are the Python installations that are potentially functional, and you could get rid of the rest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 'py -3 -m pip install matplotlib' and 'py -0p' doesn't work, the console return "invalid syntax".
So I uninstall python and I clean path environment and it works ! Thank you @sinoroc